# grepとxargsを組み合わせて複数文字列の検索を行いたい

Tags: linux

下記のやりたいことを実現するコマンドをご教示ください。

### 前提条件

$ ls
log1
log2
log3

$ cat word.txt
apple
google
facebook

### 試したコマンド

$ cat word.txt | xargs grep -nr .
これだとうまくいかない！

### やりたいこと

apple, google, facebookという文字列の最低でもいずれかを含む行を、カレントディレクトリにあるlog1-3から検索したい。find, grep, xargsの組み合わせで、特定の単語を、複数のファイルを対象にして検索する方法はぐぐったらでてくるのですが、自分がやりたいことが発見できずでして。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Linux であれば GNU grep だと思われますので、`-f` オプションを使うとか。`grep -f word.txt log{1..3}`

Comment: そのオプション知らなかったです！助かりました。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 4):

Linux であれば GNU grep だと思われますので、`-f`オプションを使うとか。

```
$ grep -f word.txt log{1..3}
```

([metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis)さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/39172/grep%E3%81%A8xargs%E3%82%92%E7%B5%84%E3%81%BF%E5%90%88%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A6%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%AE%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84/51368#comment39575_39172)より)

Comment: [POSIX `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/utilities/grep.html) にも `-f` オプションあります。