# シェルスクリプト上でファイルに含まれる行を抽出

Tags: grep

以下のような２つのファイルtest1.txt（スペース区切り）, test2.txtがあり、
test2.txtの文字列が含まれるtest1.txtの行を抽出したファイル（test3.txt）を生成するためのシェルスクリプトのコードをご教示いただくことはできないでしょうか。

■test1.txt
AAA a b
BBB b c
CCC c d
DDD d e
EEE e f

■test2.txt
AAA
CCC
EEE

■test3.txt
AAA a b
CCC c d
EEE e f

Comment: 参考: [grepとxargsを組み合わせて複数文字列の検索を行いたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/39172/)

Answer (score 2):

grep の `-f` (`--file=FILE`) オプションを利用するのが良さそうです。

> -f FILE, --file=FILE パターンを FILE から 1 行 1 パターンとして読み込みます。 このオプションを複数回使ったときや、 -e (--regexp) オプションと組み合わせたときは、与えられたすべてのパターンを検索します。
>   空のファイルはパターンを含まないので、何にもマッチしません。

https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_grep/man1/grep.1.html

実行例：

```
$ grep -f test2.txt test1.txt > test3.txt
$ cat test3.txt
AAA a b
CCC c d
EEE e f
```

Answer (score 1):

環境がLinux（GNU coreutils）であれば、joinコマンドが使えます。SQLの内部結合に相当します。

```
$ join test1.txt test2.txt
AAA a b
CCC c d
EEE e f
```

Comment: join コマンドの場合、入力データがソートされている事が前提となります。なので、`join <(sort -k1,1 test1.txt) <(sort -k1,1 test2.txt)` としておく方が無難かと思われます。

Answer (score 0):

標準入力へリダイレクトを用いて，

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
        grep $line ./test1.txt >> ./test3.txt
done < ./test2.txt
```

というのはどうでしょうか．